# How to use the result of SMEMBERS as input for SUNION in a Lua script

Tags: lua, redis

I'm trying to produce a Lua script that takes the members of a set (each representing a set as well) and returs the union.
This is a concrete example with these 3 sets:

```
smembers u:1:skt:n1
1) "s2"
2) "s3"
3) "s1"

smembers u:1:skt:n2
1) "s4"
2) "s5"
3) "s6"

smembers u:1:skts
1) "u:1:skt:n1"
2) "u:1:skt:n2"
```

So the set `u:1:skts` contains the reference of the other 2 sets and I
 want to produce the union of `u:1:skt:n1` and `u:1:skt:n2` as follows:

```
1) "s1"
2) "s2"
3) "s3"
4) "s4"
5) "s5"
6) "s6"
```

This is what I have so far:

```
local indexes = redis.call("smembers", KEYS[1])
return redis.call("sunion", indexes)
```

But I get the following error:

```
(error) ERR Error running script (call to f_c4d338bdf036fbb9f77e5ea42880dc185d57ede4): 
@user_script:1: @user_script: 1: Lua redis() command arguments must be strings or integers
```

It seems like it doesn't like the `indexes` variable as input of the `sunion` command. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not do this, or you'll have trouble moving to the cluster. This is from the [documentation](https://redis.io/commands/eval):

> All Redis commands must be analyzed before execution to determine which keys the command will operate on. In order for this to be true for EVAL, keys must be passed explicitly. This is useful in many ways, but especially to make sure Redis Cluster can forward your request to the appropriate cluster node.
>
> Note this rule is not enforced in order to provide the user with opportunities to abuse the Redis single instance configuration, at the cost of writing scripts not compatible with Redis Cluster.

If you still decide to go against the rules, use Lua's [`unpack`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-unpack):

```
local indexes = redis.call("smembers", KEYS[1])
return redis.call("sunion", unpack(indexes))
```

Comment: I dont get the phrase "keys must be passed explicitly". Maybe the command should be `local indexes = redis.call("smembers", "u:1:skts")` ? If that is the case, I could write the code inline and provide it to eval, without passing any key as input.

Comment: The line means you need to pass the key names to the script from the calling client. The script should only touch keys that are passed with the `KEYS` Lua table.

Comment: I did some more research based on your input and I now understand the problem. I see there is a way to solve the problem which is hash tags. I am going to investigate this now, but if you have some advice on how to achieve that I'm all ears.

Comment: I have many advices, but it would be better if you open a new question that's focused on what you're seeking.

Comment: Thanks, I opened another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256352/implement-reference-sets-in-redis