# Implement reference sets in Redis

Tags: lua, redis

I need to build a structure in Redis to model the following problem that involes 3 entities: user, node and socket (all string ids).
For example, the user U1 can connect to the node N1 with the sockets S1 and S2, but also he can connect to the node N2 with the sockets S3 and S4.

I must be able to easily update the sockets connected to a node of a specific user, as he connects or disconnects.
Also, each socket must expire after a certain amount of time if no action is taken.
At any given time I need to know if a user is connected with at least one socket (independently of the node).

I modeled the problem using 2 kinds of set (I used hashtag for the cluster):
1- a set with key {u:U1}skt:NX, which contains sockets connected , for example, to N1 for the user U1
2- a set with key {u:U1}skts, that contains the other sets, for example, "{u:U1}skt:N1", "{u:U1}skt:N2", ...

With this structure I can easily update the sets {u:U1}skt:NX, by adding or removing members. Also I can use the following lua script to check if a user is connected with a socket (regardless of the node).

```
local indexes = redis.call("smembers", KEYS[1])
return redis.call("sunion", unpack(indexes))
```

Is this the right approach? How can I implement the expire time of a member of a set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis does not sport expiry of data structures' contents. A common pattern to implement expiry in Sets is to use Sorted Sets instead, storing a timestamp or version value in the elements' score. Expiry then becomes a simple matter of removing members having low enough scores (with the [`ZREMBYSCORE`](https://redis.io/commands/zrembyscore) command).